# Are Type I and Type II errors in multiclass problem appear to be the same?

Tags: multi-class, confusion-matrix, type-i-and-ii-errors

As far as I know from binary classification

- FP error is a type 1 error
- FN error is a type 2 error

I have this confusion matrix generated:
[image: confmatrix]

And here I found how to read this confusion matrix:
[image: readconfmatrix]

As you can see 10% elements of SSTI have been misclassified (first pic).

If I look from SSTI side it was a FN error (type 2 error). But if I look from XSS side this error appears to be FP (type 1 error).

How to know what kind of an error made my prediction model: type 1 or type 2 error?

Comment: What is your null hypothesis?

Comment: @mhdadk, I don't know how to find null hypothesis in multicalss problem

Comment: @mhdadk, how can I find null hypothesis in multiclass problem?

Comment: The definition of FP and FN is relative in this case. I think following common convention in for what each is would be a good idea.

Comment: @mhdadk, that means I have 7 hypothesis?

Comment: As you point out, false positives and false negatives are appropriate for binary classification. Choose a metric appropriate for multiclass classification. Some options are listed here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics